# Faraday::ConnectionFailed Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, faraday

I have add elasticsearch in my rails app, also i have include these gems in my Gemfile:

```
gem "elasticsearch-rails"
gem "elasticsearch-model"
gem 'ngram'
```

All work fine, but every time when i restart my pc i get this error message

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
```

Every time i need to reinstall eleasticsearch to make it work.

I saw in other posts that for some people `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart`
solve the problem but not for me. I'm using Ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activejob (= 4.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.2)
      activemodel (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    arel (6.0.3)
    autoprefixer-rails (5.2.1.1)
      execjs
      json
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.5.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.0)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.10)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (5.0.0)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    elasticsearch (1.0.12)
      elasticsearch-api (= 1.0.12)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 1.0.12)
    elasticsearch-api (1.0.12)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-model (0.1.7)
      activesupport (> 3)
      elasticsearch (> 0.4)
      hashie
    elasticsearch-rails (0.1.7)
    elasticsearch-transport (1.0.12)
      faraday
      multi_json
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.5.2)
    faker (1.4.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    font-awesome-rails (4.4.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    guard (2.12.8)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, <= 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-minitest (2.3.1)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    hashie (3.4.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    listen (3.0.1)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.6.1)
    mini_backtrace (0.1.3)
      minitest (> 1.2.0)
      rails (>= 2.3.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.0)
    minitest-reporters (1.0.5)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nenv (0.2.0)
    ngram (1.0.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    notiffany (0.0.6)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    pg (0.17.1)
    pry (0.10.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    puma (2.11.1)
      rack (>= 1.1, < 2.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.2)
      activejob (= 4.2.2)
      activemodel (= 4.2.2)
      activerecord (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.2)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
    railties (4.2.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.5)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.7.5)
    sass (3.4.16)
    sass-rails (5.0.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.3.6)
    sprockets (3.3.1)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.7)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  autoprefixer-rails
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.1)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 0.0.10)
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  elasticsearch-model
  elasticsearch-rails
  faker (= 1.4.2)
  font-awesome-rails
  guard-minitest (= 2.3.1)
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  mini_backtrace (= 0.1.3)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.0.5)
  ngram
  pg (= 0.17.1)
  puma (= 2.11.1)
  rails (= 4.2.2)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.2)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (= 2.5.3)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
  will_paginate (= 3.0.7)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Comment: It's probably because your Elasticsearch server doesn't start automatically when your boot your PC. Have you installed your Elasticsearch server [as a service](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because your Elasticsearch server doesn't start automatically when you boot your PC.

If you install your Elasticsearch server [as a service](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html) and configure it properly, the problem will go away.

Comment: Note for future people: if you have ubuntu/debian, This command line might make it work: sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start  (Note, the answert above is correct this is just the necessary code)